# Syntaxe Error with variable on Databse (MySQL / Python)

Tags: python, mysql, database, scrapy

at first I declared a variable "nom_of_game_db", but after that I can't find the correct syntax at the level of the MySQL to call the variable back:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

name_of_game_db = input("Name of game ?")

class QuotetutorialPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
                host = 'localhost',
                user = 'root',
                passwd = 'jozefleonel',
                database = 'prices'
            )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nam_of_game_db""")
        self.curr.execute("""create table name_of_game_db(
                        name text,
                        platform text,
                        edition text
                        )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self,item):
        self.curr.execute("""insert into name_of_game_db values (%s,%s,%s)""", (
            item['name'][0],
            item['platform'][0],
            item['edition'][0]
            ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

I use Python and MySQL

Comment: Show us the error.

Answer (score 0):

After doing the execute to create table statement use self.conn.commit() to commit the db changes.and also rename the drop table exist sql command.

Comment: i want just to find the good syntaxe to call the value of the variable

Comment: Define the variable as global